# what is the default password of Splunk enterprises

Tags: splunk

I have configured splunk from AWS marketplace, I am unable to login using default password.

user name: admin
password: changeme

also i tried below password

SPLUNK-{i-00014d5f17644a8e0}

Answer (score 1):

The "changeme" password hasn't been used since Splunk 7.1.

According to the AMI's usage instructions, the password is the text "SPLUNK-" followed by your instance's ID.  Since instance IDs do not contain braces, you might try `SPLUNK-i-00014d5f17644a8e0`.